# Entity Framework default value for null properties on select

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I am possibly looking at moving from nHibernate for my ORM to entity framework and I am running into a small issue if the database is has a null value, but the entity property is not nullable.  nHibernate will just set the default value and move on and will not cause any exceptions.  Meaning if I have a boolean property it will be false if the database is null.

In entity framework (6) it throws an exception.  Is there some configuration setting that I am missing to tell EF to set a default value if the property is not nullable and the database value is null?

Comment: Why property is not nullable when database column is? they are supposed to map exactly, EF is not tolerating such things.

Comment: No, EF doesn't support that (the list of not supported features as compared to NHibernate is pretty long. Its LINQ support is the USP).

Comment: @IvanStoev, we have issues where the database developers will change a column to nullable and add null values to it without telling the developers  .  I agree with you if the developer managed everything in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your entity properties don't have to be automatic properties, so you could, for instance do:

```
public class SomeEntity
{
  private bool _field
  public bool? Field
  {
    get { return _field; }
    set { _field = value.HasValue ? false : value.Value; }
  }
}
```